# intersection curve of 3D mesh object and 2D plane

Tags: c#, 3d

I need a computer graphics book that gives the intersection curve of 3D mesh object and 2D plane.
Could you advise me a book.

Answer (score 2):

[Real-Time Collision Detection](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/1558607323/realtimecolli-20/) by Christer Ericson could be a good choice for you since it covers many basic geometry intersection tests. Take a look at its [table of contents](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/books/rtcd/toc/).